# Prove that $|A| < |A| + h(A)$ for all $A$

Tags: set-theory

Prove that $|A| < |A| + h(A)$ for all $A$, where $h(A)$ is the Hartogs number of $A$.

Attempt: By definition, $h(A) > 0$ because it is the least ordinal number which is not equipotent to any subset of $A$. Hence, we have $|A| + h(A) > |A|$.

Question: Is the proof as simple as this? I think I am missing something here.

This question is from 'Introduction to Set Theory' by Hrbacek and Jech, chapter $7$ Q$1.4$

Comment: You say By definition $ h(A) \gt 0 $.  Shouldn't this be $ h(A) \gt |A| $.

Comment: Fortunately, $|A| \ge 0$.

Comment: $\kappa>0$ does not imply $\kappa+\lambda>\lambda$. For example, $\aleph_0>0$ but $\aleph_1+\aleph_0=\aleph_1$.

Comment: @NickR: I think it should be $|h(A)| > |A|$.

Comment: I think $ h(A) $ is a cardinal number, by definition.  If so, then you need not uses the $ | | $.  I guess there's no harm either way.

Comment: @Nick R: IS it always true that $|h(A)|=h(A)$?

Comment: I believe it is.  When one writes cardinal-arithmetic expressions, one doesn't use $ | \lambda | + | \kappa | $, just $ \lambda + \kappa $.  I should mention I am using the wiki definition of $ h(A) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof has some missing point: how to imply $|A|+h(A)>|A|$ from $h(A)>0$? There is no reason that $\kappa+\lambda>\lambda$ despite $\kappa>0$ holds. For example, $\aleph_0>0$ but $\aleph_1+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

However, proof of this problem is not too hard. Although $\kappa>0$ does not imply strict inequality $\kappa+\lambda>\lambda$, it implies $\kappa+\lambda\ge\lambda$. If $|A|+h(A)=|A|$ then $h(A)\le |A|$ and it contradicts the definition of $h(A)$.

Comment: I don understand how to get the last sentence 'If ... then ...'

Comment: If $|A|+h(A)=|A|$ then $h(A)\le |A|+h(A)=|A|$. You know the definition of Hartogs number.

Comment: In the example given above, you are using cardinal arithmetic. But $h(A)$ is an ordinal, will it affect the arithmetic? Because cardinal arithmetic is not the same as ordinal arithmetic.

Comment: $h(A)$ is ordinal and also a cardinal. It does not affect the arithmetic.